# Flutter Firebase instant SearchBar

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, instantsearch

How can I do instant search in Flutter  Firebase?

For example I have Brands list in my Firebase Documents like this; [image: Brands Doc]

and I want to do Search instantly in list for example when I text "F" I want to display Ford and Fiat or when I text "Te" I want to display Tesla. So whatever I type in the search bar, I want the strings containing those words or letters to appear on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [this one](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/implement-searching-with-firebase-firestore-flutter-de7ebd53c8c9)

Here is the sample of query, (You can create by your own way)

```
List<DocumentSnapshot> documentList = (await Firestore.instance
        .collection("cases")
        .document(await firestoreProvider.getUid())
        .collection(caseCategory)
        .where("caseNumber", arrayContains: query) // query param will be your search string
        .getDocuments())
    .documents;
```

Comment: It's a working solution, but I  need to enter all possible variables into the database beforehand. If I want to view Tesla, I need to enter T, Te, Tes, Tesl, Tesla data for Tesla. It's too long for me to do this for every brand and when the database is updated every time, I also need to do it.

Comment: I think it should have a dynamic solution

Comment: It will count transaction for every query so better to get all the values in one list and try to filter data from List.